# Bad Essential Matrix With OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, projective-geometry

#### Overview

I'm writing a simple Python program to calculate the distance to a chosen target from a pair of two arbitrarily located stereo images. Both images are taken from a single camera with known intrinsics **K**, and although the camera locations and poses are arbitrary, I always know the baseline distance between locations.

I believe I'm having issues getting a good essential matrix from OpenCV and I can't figure out whether this is the case or I'm just interpreting the results incorrectly. Here is a sample image pair: [Stereo image pair (left camera on left, right camera on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5forx.jpg) (If someone could put the images inline that would be much appreciated :P).

My imagery is currently from an iPhone 12 camera which almost certainly comes undistorted automatically. I still calibrated the camera anyways but am not unidstorting anything at any point in my script. (should I be?)

#### Method

The process I currently use for computing geometry is as follows:

1. Perform keypoint detection and matching to obtain two lists of corresponding image points
2. Calculate the essential matrix **E** using OpenCV's 5-point algorithm `cv2.findEssentialMat()`. I use RANSAC here for outlier filtering.
3. Recover rotation matrix **R** and translation unit vector **t** from **E** using OpenCV's `cv2.recoverPose()`. Here I also multiply **t** by the baseline distance to get real-world scale.

#### Problems

The resulting calculated rotation and translation do not match expected results. I will start by asserting that my keypoint detection and matching is very good and is almost certainly not the culprit of my issues. The left image was taken head-on and the right image was taken 7m to the right and then angled in towards the scene, so I would expect a translation from the left camera to the right camera of **t** = [7, 0, 0]. Instead I am getting **t** = [-6.597, 0.256, 2.324] from `cv2.recoverPose()`. Could I be interpreting the coordinate frame of this result incorrectly? Could this instead be the translation from the right camera to the left? Or could `cv2.recoverPose()` be converging on the wrong solution (unlikely)?

Visualizing the epilines on the images also raises concern:
[Images with epilines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbKdo.jpg). I read that the 8-point algorithm to find the fundamental matrix was sensitive to noise so I decided to back solve for the fundamental matrix using `F = Kinv.T @ E @ Kinv` where **Kinv** is the inverse of the intrinsics matrix **K**. Looking at the resulting corresponding epilines, it appears as if the "other" camera is to the left of the imaging camera in *BOTH* images. This obviously doesn't make sense. Additionally, changing the algorithm or RANSAC parameters sometimes drastically changes the resulting image: [Same stereo images with different RANSAC parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PaIF.jpg) The epipoles should not be visible in either image, and in this case the calculated **R** and **t** are obviously incorrect.

Is the poor performance a result of noise in the system? A very good homography is easily obtained (`cv2.findHomography()`) as visualized here: [left image warped onto right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F79eJ.jpg) and I curated this pair of images for best performance (by imaging a wall). Could the small amount of parallax in the system be adding noise? Noise is clearly filtered out for the homography and I'm passing the 5-point algorithm nearly 1500 pairs of matched points for these images.

At the end of the day, I need to get accurate **R** and **t** between perspectives and it seems to me that a better **E** matrix is necessary first to do so. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

#### Code

Note: assume `pts0` and `pts1` are appropriately populated with good correspondences (left and right respectively).

```python
# matched points in each image
pts0 = np.int32(<left image points here>)
pts1 = np.int32(<corresponding right image points here>)    

E, mask = cv2.findEssentialMat(pts0, pts1, K, cv2.RANSAC, prob=.99999, threshold=.1)
F = Kinv.T @ E @ Kinv # solve for fundamental matrix

# recover pose to verify calculated transform to actual camera placement
_, R, t, _ = cv2.recoverPose(E, pts0, pts1, K, mask=mask)
t *= scale # convert to real-world scale

pts0 = pts0[mask.ravel() == 1]
pts1 = pts1[mask.ravel() == 1]

"""
followed tutorial at <https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html>
for displaying epilines
"""
llines = cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(pts1.reshape(-1, 1, 2), 2, F)
llines = llines.reshape(-1, 3)
out02, _ = drawlines(left_img, right_img, llines, pts0, pts1)
rlines = cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(pts0.reshape(-1, 1, 2), 1, F)
rlines = rlines.reshape(-1, 3)
out01, _ = drawlines(right_img, left_img, rlines, pts1, pts0)

cv2.imshow('epilines', np.hstack((out02, out01)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

so looking at the images, it's likely (?) most features lie on a single plane, in which case estimating the essential matrix from these points has known degeneracies (see Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision, section 11.9 )

also using a simulated problem first helps to ensure your code is correct (e.g. sample N random 3d points, define 2 Poses and project to the 2 corresponding images, compare the output with the expected essential matrix derived from the 2 poses)